# Theorem 1.40 from Rudin RCA

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

Hello! I read this theorem and understood it. But let me ask you one question: where did he use that $\mu(X)<\infty$? Is this condition crucial?

Answer (score 4):

The claimed equality
$$ |A_E(f) - \alpha| = \frac{1}{\mu(E)}\left| \int_E (f - \alpha)\,d\mu\right|$$
depends on the assertion
$$\frac{1}{\mu(E)}\int_E \alpha\,d\mu = \frac{1}{\mu(E)}\mu(E)\alpha =  \alpha.$$
This is not valid if $\mu(E) = \infty$. And we cannot in general rule this case out if $\mu(X) = \infty$.

Answer (score 3):

He uses the fact that $$\frac1{\mu(E)}\int_E\alpha\,d\mu=\alpha.$$If $\mu(E)=\infty$ then $\int_E\alpha\,d\mu$ is undefined. Or maybe it's defined for $\alpha\ge0$; in any case, whatever value we give to that integral we still have $$\frac1{\mu(E)}\int_E\alpha\,d\mu=0.$$

The result is still true if $\mu(X)=\infty$. But offhand the only proof I see requires splitting into two cases. If $\mu(X)<\infty$ then [what he said]. Assume $\mu(X)=\infty$. Since $f\in L^1(\mu)$ it follows that $0\in S$. Now [what he said, up to the point where we say $E$ is the inverse image of that disk]. If $\mu(E)=\infty$ then $A_E(f)=0\in S$. On the other hand, if $\mu(E)<\infty$ then [what he said].